# Server Return error 404 while uploading documents on oracle cloud infrastructure

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I can list the object of the bucket using API from oracle cloud infrastructure.But when I try to upload file it shows an error 404.I am not sure whether URI is correct or I am not authorized.

here the code snippet:

```
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(FileUpload1.FileName);
            byte[] filebyte =FileUpload1.FileBytes;
            var myfirstobject = FileUpload1.FileName;
            Response.Write(myfirstobject);
            var postdata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(filebyte.ToString());

            var tenancyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BMCTenancyId"];
            var userId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BMCUserId"];
            var fingerprint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BMCFingerprint"];
            var privateKeyPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BMCPrivateKeyPath"];
            var privateKeyPassphrase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BMCPrivateKeyPassphrase"];
            var bucket= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BMCBucket"];
            var Namespace= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BMCNamespace"];

            var signer = new RequestSigner(tenancyId, userId, fingerprint, privateKeyPath, privateKeyPassphrase);

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            var uri = new Uri($"https://objectstorage.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com/n/{Namespace}/b/{bucket}/{myobject}");

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = "PUT";
           request.ContentType = "application/json";
          request.ContentLength = postdata.Length;
        request.Headers["x-content-sha256"] = Convert.ToBase64String(SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(bytes));

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        signer.SignRequest(request);


        ExecuteRequest(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the same action from the OCI console, using the same user as you are using from the code above (`BMCUserId`)? If not, then you are not authorized to perform the action, and its not an issue with your code. Otherwise, its an issue with your code.